# How to show menu or popup above barchart of on item click of each bar in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell How to show menu or popup above barchart of on item click of each bar in extjs4.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In series you can lister to `itemmousedown` event and code for menu.

Refer: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.chart.Chart-cfg-series.

Instead of 'afterrender' you can use your event.